# facebook access tokens expiration unclear

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I have been using multiple access tokens from different registered web applications for a while now and what I have noticed is that when I expect an access_token to expire after 60 days; it still actually is able to keep on making requests to the api without any errors. According to facebook documentation this should not be the case. Has anyone experienced the same scenario or are these actually automatically renewed. When trying to get info on the tokens from the graph api, all I get returned is the app id and valid status.

```
{
  "data": {
     "app_id": 123456789,
     "is_valid": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You query is not clear, can you pls elaborate a bit what's exactly the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) says that the official SDKs will automatically renew access tokens when necessary. They will expire only if you do not use that access_token for its lifetime duration (in your case for 60 days) in any api calls.

Comment: I saw that but thought it referred to:  When using iOS, Android or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle making sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire.

Comment: While I did not do a direct research regarding the php sdk, I used it for many projects and never had any problems related to access_token expiration while the app was used regularly by the users. It could have been a coincidence too of course:)